# Listing items within a category (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set like the following:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+
| job_code        | job_title           |
+-----------------+---------------------+
| finance_acct    | Business Accountant |
| finance_manager | Business Manager    |
| it_programmer   | IT Programmer       |
| it_manager      | IT Manager          |
+-----------------+---------------------+
```

etc.

I want to take all of the job titles that share the same first half of their job code and print them as a list. Like the following:

finance: Business Accountant, Business Manager

it: IT Programmer, IT Manager

How would I do so? I know how to use `SUBSTR` to pull the first part of the job code. Basically I can create the left column fine. I ran into a couple of problems though:

1. Using the `GROUP BY` command, I continually got ORA-00979 error ("not
   a GROUP BY expression").
2. I can't figure out how to make the list delimited with commas. I
   used `CONCAT` but even then you end up with a superfluous comma after
   the last entry for a given line. I've seen some things online about
   the `STUFF` command, but I know it's possible to do so without this.

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do this is to **add a column** to indicate the category, as well as likely a separate table so you can separate category from category description.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle DB server are you using? This may impact available options (e.g. the mentioned `listagg` function was not available in older versions).

Answer (score 2):

`regexp_substr()` comes to mind to extract the part you want from the `job_code`.  The rest is just aggregation and `listagg()`:

```
select regexp_substr(job_code, '[^_]+', 1, 1) as half_job_code,
       listagg(job_title, ', ') within group (order by job_title) as job_titles
from t
group by regexp_substr(job_code, '[^_]+', 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function. you can specify a delimited and group it based on the data you require.